# get-azurekeyvaultkey does not return "public key"

Tags: azure-keyvault

I am just testing out Azure Key Vault with key/pairs and am attempting to retrieve the public key.

I first created a `Key Vault` (name = "VaultTest") using Azure portal.

I then created a `Key` (Name = "TestKey1") again using Azure portal.

I see the key in the portal and when I click on it I see the following information:

> ***Properties***:
>
> ```
> Key Type: RSA
>
> RSA Key Size 2048
>
> Created: "date time"
>
> Updated: "date time"
>
> Key Identifier: //vault path/keys/TestKey1/Key identifier
> ```
>
> ***Settings***:
>
> ```
> Set activation date: "unchecked"
>
> Set expiration date: "unchecked"
>
> Enabled: True
>
> Tags "none"
>
> Permitted operations:
>
> Encrypt: true
>
> Decrypt: true
>
> Sign: true
>
> Verify: true
>
> Wrap key: true
>
> Unwrap key: true
> ```

Notice that there is no public key information displayed so I switched over to Azure Cloud Shell and executed the following command:

```
Get-AzureKeyVaultKey -vaultname 'VaultTest' -name 'TestKey1'
```

It returns VaultName, Name, Version, Id, Enabled, Expires, Not Before, Created, Updated, Purge Disabled and Tags, but no Key.

All the examples I read online (albeit somewhat old) show fields `Attributes` and `Key` being returned but those are not returning for me.

I read somewhere that if you call the URI it will return the public key info, so I copy/pasted the URI into a browser but this returns to me:

> *{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token."}}*

Am I doing something brain dead or has the function get-azurekeyvaultkey changed? If it has changed how does one get the public key information for a specific key stored in Key Vault?

Comment: You can also use API to get  key information
{vaultBaseUrl}/keys/{key-name}/{key-version}?api-version=7.0 


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getkey/getkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue with `Get-AzureKeyVaultKey -vaultname 'VaultTest' -name 'TestKey1'`.

[image]

But actually it returns the `Attributes` and `Key` that you want, just pass the `| ConvertTo-Json` like below.

```
Get-AzureKeyVaultKey -vaultname 'VaultTest' -name 'TestKey1' | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Joy, that worked! This is why I love StackOverflow so much, nowhere in the MS documentation for this function did it mention you needed to convert to Json to see all the information being returned. A simple example on their part would save people so much time (imo).