# Powershell write to variable instead of file

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to use Azure powershell to pull an SSH key and add it to a VM.
The cmdlet is

`Get-AzKeyVaultKey ... -OutFile filename`

I'd like to avoid actually writing the key to the disk, but I need it in a variable. Is there any way to provide a variable acting like a file or something so I can go

`-OutFile $someVariablePretendingToBeFile`

and use that variable please?

The variable that is returned by Get-AzKeyVaultKey is of type [PsKeyVaultKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.keyvault.models.pskeyvaultkey?view=azurerm-ps)
if I get its `key` property, and call ToRSA() I get an [RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=net-5.0#methods)
But I still don't see where to get the public key string from!
It's annoying b/c -OutFile produces exactly the public key

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$someVariablePretendingToBeFile = Get-AzKeyVaultKey ...` (and remove `-OutFile filename`) ?

Comment: Hi, yeah that returns a [PSKeyVaultKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.keyvault.models.pskeyvaultkey?view=azurerm-ps) but I can't seem to find any way to extract the public key from that object

Comment: You'll have to dig deeper into the returned object. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60312396/9898643)

Comment: Hi - yeah I saw that answer, and it still doesn't clear up where to get the public key from. By calling $key.key.ToRSA() I get an [rsacryptoserviceprovider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=net-5.0#methods) But I don't see where to get the pub key from that. It's annoying because -OutFile gives me exactly what I want!

Comment: I have a feeling I'm going to have to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406888/c-sharp-rsa-public-key-output-not-correct/28407693#28407693) if I can't mock the variable

Comment: Wow... I hope you get it right. If you do, please post it as answer for others to benefit.

Comment: Found the code that does it in [et-AzKeyVaultKey](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/91ece8f6138350a8fd5a9db93710766aa498a1ac/src/KeyVault/KeyVault/Commands/GetAzureKeyVaultKey.cs#L436)

Comment: The Azure powershell code that exports the public key uses the Stackoverflow answer linked above(!)[here they've commented that answer above the same impl](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/91ece8f6138350a8fd5a9db93710766aa498a1ac/src/KeyVault/KeyVault/Helpers/JwkHelper.cs#L30)

Comment: Well done! Good find

Answer (score 0):

Since Get-AzKeyVaultKey is not providing a way of doing (that I know of), can you get it to work with a simple :

$key=(Get-AzKeyVaultKey XXX)

To get the result in a variable ?

Let us know !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if tis would work, it is a variant of the answer above. I can't test it just now

```
$PublicKey = Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName $vaultName -KeyName $keyName
```